# Picker delegate scrolling method in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, uipickerview, swiftui

I have simple `Picker` object in my SwiftUI hierarchy:

```
Picker(selection: $pickerSelection, label: Text("Select your item")) {
    ForEach(0 ..< items.count) {
        Text("\(self.items[$0].valueCode)")
            .tag($0)
    }
}
```

I'm using a scrollable Picker in WatchOS app and it works just fine. I'm even getting a Digital Crown rotation capability for free.

What I want to do is to detect when the scrolling started and *especially* ended (to get last selected value and execute and action with it)

I figure I need to implement sort of Delegate method to read the changes happening to the Picker but I'm not sure how, nor I'm able to find any in the documentation for `WKInterfacePicker` or just `Picker`

Any suggestions on how to detect the beginning and end of the scrolling event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If its about the last value you can use Combine and subscribe to pickerSelection.

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    private var disposables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    @Published var pickerSelection = 0
    
    init() {
        let cc = $pickerSelection
            .sink(receiveValue: { value in
                print(value)
            })
        cc.store(in: &disposables)
    }
    
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var mm = ViewModel()
    
    var items = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            Text("Hello, World!")
            Picker(selection: self.$mm.pickerSelection, label: Text("Item:")) {
                ForEach(0 ..< items.count) {
                    Text("Item \($0)")
                        .tag($0)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```